# Equal rectifier capacitor

Tags: capacitor, rectifier

Capacity of the capacitor in circuit below is equal:
[image]

What difference is there between the circuits?
Which one is better?
Can i made equal the capacitor with the capacitors in series?

Which one is Effective Cost?why Usually people usage one capacitor Instead some capacitors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What difference is there between the circuits? Which one is better?
>   Can i made equal the capacitor with the capacitors in series?

Theoretically and simplistically both are as good as each other but you might find that the practicality of "one capacitor" makes it "better" whereas the likelihood of 6 parallel caps performing better on ripple current and ESR (effective series resistance) is to be considered favourably for the 6-cap solution.

To get 6000 uF with 6 series caps requires 6x 36,000 uF caps and the advantage is that you can use a lower voltage rating but only if you use bleed resistor to equalize the standing dc voltages across each cap.

Answer (score 3):

I have the impression you are implying a string of *parallel* capacitors, like drawn in the lower half of the image. Not to confuse with series capacitors that are connected end to end to end to ...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyGj6r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One of the problems you may be facing is that the wires between capacitor and load are not ideal. They have a given length and with length comes resistance and inductance.

So you can theoretically use a single huge capacitor, but when the connecting wires are getting longer, the effect of the capacitor is reduced due to wire impedance. It is good practice to connect a capacitor as close to the load as viably possible to reduce the effect of the connecting wires. For the same reason, when you look at a populated PCB, you'll see many small capacitors distributed across the board, all placed on the power rails, but near to a (small) load (eg. IC's).